# php shell_exec run my php file many times

Tags: php, shell

i have ubuntu 20.0.4 server .
when i run php8.1 using shell_exec :

**1 - it's getting bug either from terminal or web server**

**2- checking commands by using** `htop->commands` **there are many commands that executing at same time and my cpu usage up to `100%` .**

example :

```
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
sh -c php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php
```

**my current code :**

```
$e = shell_exec("php /var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php");
print_r($e);
```

**any help?**

Comment: Is your current code saved at `/var/www/html/broadcast/new_broadcast.php`?

Comment: yes my current code there.

Comment: Every time you evaluate the first line, you create another process that runs the script, the second process starts before the first script can reach `print_r($e)`. Then the second process tries to call `shell_exec...` again, so you get a third process. And so on. This is similar to infinite recursion.

Comment: no. 
i found that i must use cd /var/www/html && php new_broadcast.php to solve this problem. my another server doesnt need this command to work .

Comment: Seems like you have another file located at `/var/www/html/new_broadcast.php`

Comment: nope, the shell execute command from directory root..

Comment: Even if you executed from the root, you ran `cd /var/www/html` first, so the php file should be found at that location. You probably have another `new_broadcast.php` with a full path of `/var/www/html/new_broadcast.php`.